# ajax return data using bootstrap modal can't get parameter inside modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to submit a data parameter using PHP Codeigniter that comes from ajax return data, but when I submit the form, I can't get this parameter.

HTML :

```
 <a href="#myModalBiaya" class="trash" role="button" data-toggle="modal">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="pdetailbiaya" value="Detail Biaya" >Detail Biaya</button>
               </a>
```

JS :

```
$('#myModalBiaya').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
           po_id = $('#po_id').val();
           $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>admin/po_trans_receive_po/getBiaya',
        data:'po_id='+po_id,
                  success: function(data){
                      $("#myModalBiaya .tdata").html(data);
        }
      });
  });
```

Modal :

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="panel panel-default" >
                   <div class="panel-heading">
                     <div class="form-horizontal tdata" >
                    <div class="form-group" >
<label class='col-md-3 control-label' for='menu_name'>Biaya PPN </label>  
                         <div class='col-md-8'> 
                           <input type="text" name="po_biaya_ppn" id="po_biaya_ppn" readonly onkeyup="getTotalBiaya()"class="form-control text-right" value="0">
                         </div>
                        </div>
...
```

PHP :

```
 function getBiaya()
 {
     $po_id = $this->input->post('po_id');
     $resultPO = $this->md_po_trans_po->getID($po_id);

if ($resultPO) {
             $resultotal = $resultPO->po_biaya_ppn+$resultPO->po_ongkos_angkut+$resultPO->po_biaya_asuransi+$resultPO->po_biaya_materai;

  echo '      <div class="form-group" >                                                                                                                                                      ';
    echo '              <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Biaya PPN </label>                                                                                                                 ';
    echo '               <div class="col-md-8">                                                                                                                                                  ';
    echo '                 <input type="text" name="po_biaya_ppn" id="po_biaya_ppn" readonly onkeyup="getTotalBiaya()" class="form-control text-right" value="'.$resultPO->po_biaya_ppn.'">       ';
    echo '               </div>                                                                                                                                                                  ';
    echo '                  </div>     ';
}
```

Everything works unless the input parameter `po_biaya_ppn` is blank when I submit this form. When I `print_r($this->input->post('po_biaya_ppn'));die();` this is returned blank.

Regards,
Thank You

Comment: Any reason you dont just return the required value rather than all that duplicated HTML?

Comment: What is the value your are sending in `po_id`?

Comment: If the value you are sending in `po_id` contains characters that are not valid for a url you will need to convert them, try `data:'po_id='+encodeURIComponent(po_id),` and see if that fixes it

Comment: po_id it is for query using parameter po_id (in PHP file), is it better way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the actual value of `po_id` when it is sent in the ajax function?

Comment: this modal is detail for PO form. so po_id it is for querying detail data using po_id, actual value is integer

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of the variable `po_id`? it matters, if it is something like `1234` then converting is not required, however if it includes invalid/unexpected URL characters like `12&34`  it will mess up your query string. THis may not be the issue, but we cant rule it out until we know the value of `po_id`

Comment: po_id that send to modals it's really works , modal show perfectly. the problem is when i submit main form this input name="po_biaya_ppn" can't pass to php it's returned blank.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. In your ajax function, where you have `data:'po_id='+po_id,`, what is the value of `po_id`? This is the value that will be sent to your php page

Comment: Wait, when you say "when i submit main form" are you talking about an actual form that is submited sometime AFTER, the ajax returns and is not shown in the above code?

Comment: in this main form , i have one modal that contain of detail of main form, because there is alot of field, i'm using this modal. this modal data based on selected po_id in main form, Then when i submit this main form , input parameter in this modal returned blank when i debug

Comment: Yeah, but you dont show us that form. It does not appear that the input element `<input type="text" name="po_biaya_ppn" id="po_biaya_ppn"  .....` is actually inside the form. If this element is not actually insdie the form, it will not be sent when you submit the form. Is this the case?

Comment: <input type="text" name="po_biaya_ppn" id="po_biaya_ppn" .....> in modal and the modal inside main form. So this parameter should be post also right?

Comment: If the modal is inside the form, yes the value should be sent. Though you dont show that part so we cant completely rule out an issue there. Also, are you sure you have not mistakenly listed `name="po_biaya_ppn"` on another element in the form?

Comment: finally i've changed the way to get this data , your comment "Any reason you dont just return the required value rather than all that duplicated HTML?" makes me to search other way. thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 data:'po_id='+po_id,
```

with

```
var form_data = {
    po_id : po_id,
};
data:form_data,
```

Comment: `'po_id='+po_id` is just as valid as `{ po_id : po_id,}`

Comment: @DelightedD0D It was not in my knowledge Thanks :)

Comment: No worries, also note that If the value being sent contains characters that are not valid for a url you must convert them first with something like: `data:'po_id='+encodeURIComponent(po_id),` which would apply in either use case